# How to center Box in Column?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to center `Box` in `Column`, but I do not know why it does not work...
I have tried without `maxSize` options, without `align` and `contentAlign` in box, but with bad results.

```
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) { padding ->
        Column(
            Modifier
                .padding(padding)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .size(300.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {} 
    }
```

How to center Box in Column?

My code:

```
       Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(300.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                swipeStates.forEachIndexed { index, (product, swipeState) ->
                    if (swipeState.swipedDirection == null) {
                        ImageContent(product, swipeState)
                    } else {
                        // If any item is swiped, set the flag to false
                        isListFullySwiped = false
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(product, swipeState.swipedDirection) {
                        if (swipeState.swipedDirection != null) {
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            IconsContent(scope, swipeStates)
    }
    }
```

The problem is content in Box with `swipeStates.forEach` does not want to be centered.

Comment: What bad results are you getting? It works for me. The only thing is that "padding" comes after "fillMaxSize", but I doubt that is the problem here.